# The prop `push` is marked as required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting this warning when i call the `ReactDOM.render()` method:

> Failed prop type: The prop `push` is marked as required in
>   `Connect(Detail)`, but its value is `undefined`

This is the render call:

```
const render = Component => {
    const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
    ReactDOM.render(
            <AppContainer>
                {Component}
            </AppContainer>,
            appElement
        );
};
```

And this is my component:

```
const component = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={createBrowserHistory()}>
            {routes()}
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

Then, I call it like this:

```
render(component);
```

Do I need extra configuration on the ConnectedRouter or maybe I'm not building properly the routes and/or store?

Comment: how does the Detail component look like

Comment: Is quite big, do you think the problem could be there?

Comment: You were right, the problem was I was passing an undefined into the push property inside the Detail component (as the warning actually said), this corected the problem. Thanks.